# can we create an overlapping bar chart using highcharts?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

While going through different kinds of charts i came across a chart like this called overlapping bar chart

can we create a similar or else the same chart using highcharts?

[image: I've seen this in a forum regarding TIBCO spotfire]

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 15):

We need to set [`grouping`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.grouping) to false.

```
plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    grouping: false,
                    shadow: false
                }
            }
```

Fiddle yourself upon the sample demo **[`here`](http://jsfiddle.net/gopinaghr/q8Udk/)**.

### EDIT

I have updated it for polar charts. Find it [**`here`**](http://jsfiddle.net/gopinaghr/EAaKd/).

Comment: what if we want to have a group of such bars?

Comment: I'm trying a polar chart like this http://jsfiddle.net/QgUgW/8/ can you please help me out how i can achieve the same overlapped bars here

Comment: @strikers : please look at the edit, if that is what you needed.

Comment: Would this be possible to do horizontal as well?

Comment: Works like a charm for columnrange series in 4.0!

Comment: @M.Appelman For horizontal, you need to add `inverted: true` in `chart`.